# Something about MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new to `MongoDB`, can anyone explain how it could be used in efficiently in enterprise applications, so as to give good performance (using joins, indexing etc.)
And perhaps also point me to any MongoDB production applications on the web.

Comment: Live demo of what? Performance depends on various factors...and there are no JOINs in MongoDB...please more specific questions.

Comment: Hi, this question probably has a higher chance of survival and getting good answers if you make it more specific. Judging by your comment on the answer here, it seems you're really asking about material for learning MongoDB, is that right? If so you should really ask about that. If not, you should edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

For a good introduction to MongoDB, check out [The Little MongoDB Book](http://openmymind.net/2011/3/28/The-Little-MongoDB-Book). Here's a list of sites currently using [MongoDB in production](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments).

Comment: Thanks for your response.Let me check

Answer (score 0):

You talk about Joins and Indexes. It seems your head is still in the RDBMS world. NoSQL and Mongo are not just different Relational Databases there a completely different way of managing and thinking of Data. You need to think of your data schema in terms of Structured Objects rather than rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to start from the beginning.  [MongoDB.org](http://www.mongodb.org/) has a lot of the info you're asking for already available.  Specifically, read their page on [use cases](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases), and the page on [production deployments](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments).

A more specific question would receive more comprehensive answers and fewer downvotes.